# OData update controller throwing 415 Unsupported media type error

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an OData controller with 'Put' and 'Post' actions. When I post *Content-Type:application/json*, I get an HttpResponseException with '415: unsupported media type'. The only *Content-Type* that the controller won't throw an exception on is the *application/x-www-urlformencoded*. But that is not the content type that I want to accept.

Why does the odata controller not accept application/json? I don't see anything in the configuration of the controller that restricts the accepted content types.

I remember the same code working in the past. Soemthing seems to have regressed it. Where should I look?

Answer (score 1):

Feels lik the type that you expect in the body (i.e declared in your action as a parameter) is not part of the EDM model of your service.

For example,

```
HttpResponseMessage Post(Customer customer)
```

If customer is not part of your EDM model, web API would throw a 415. This happens as ODataControllers have only ODataMediaTypeFormatters and ODataMediaTypeFormatter supports only reading types that are declared in the model.

Comment: This might be it! Thanks you very much! I tried to add the type to the model using ODataModelBuilder.EntitySet method but getting the following model state error,"The entity type 'CustomerUpdate' is not compatible with the base type 'CustomerDTO' of the provided entity set 'Container.Customer'. When an entity type is specified for an OData feed or entry reader, it has to be the same or a subtype of the base type of the specified entity set."

Comment: I already have a CustomerDTO type for the Customer controller and now want to add a CustomerUpdate type (for POST).